# Disc. Math Proof help?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am enorolled in a community college level discrete mathematics course and am having problems with a proof I have for homework.

Suppose a, b, c, and d are integers and a≠c. Suppose also that x is a real number that satisfies the equation:

(ax + b) / (cx + d) = 1

must x be rational? If so express x as a ratio of two integers.

This is what i have so far:
let a, b, c, and d be PBAC integers 
let x = (p/q)
(cx + d) ≠ 0

(a(p/q) + b) / (c(p/q) + d) = 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ve got off on the wrong foot, I’m afraid.

HINT: Solve the equation

$$\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}=1$$

for $x$; you’ll need to use the hypothesis that $a\ne c$. Then use the hypothesis that $a,b,c$, and $d$ are all integers to decide whether $x$ must be rational.